# PHP Inserting Extra <td> tags?

Tags: php

I have the following PHP script. It works but the problem is when it retrieves data from the server, it inserts two extra `<td>` tags.

Here is the PHP Code:

```
<?php
getDirectory($_POST['selCountry'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['selRoles'], $kbconnection);
echo $_SESSION["directoryTitle"];
echo '<table class="directory-table">';
//table title
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th width="40%"><em><strong>Last, First</strong></em></th>';
echo '<th width="40%"><em><strong>Company</strong></em></th>';
echo '<th width="15%"><em><strong>City</strong></em></th>';
echo '<th width="5%"><em><strong>Action</strong></em></th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';
//table body
echo '<tbody>';
for($j = 0; $j < $gr; ++$j) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width="40%">'.$glast[$j].',  '.$gfirst[$j].'<td>';
    echo '<td width="40%">'.$gcompany[$j].'</td>';
    echo '<td width="15%">'.$gcity[$j].'</td>';
    //echo '<td>'.$country[$j].'</td>';
    echo '<td width="5%"> <a href="../DB/dbpages/dbViewDirectory4BC.php?personid='.$gid[$j].'">View</a><td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

When it renders, it renders the following code:

```
<tr>
  <td width="40%">Last Name, First</td>
  <td></td>
  <td width="40%">Company name</td>
  <td width="15%">City</td>
  <td width="5%"> <a href="../path/to/url">View</a></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see there are two empty `<td>` tags.

How do I modify the code to remove these two tags?

I didn't write the script and I don't know PHP very well, so I'm at a loss as to what is wrong.

At the very least, how do I trigger some javascript to run after the data is retrieved that can run and remove the empty `<td>` tags?

Comment: you're missing first closing `</td>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why shouldn't it?

```
echo '<td width="40%">'.$glast[$j].',  '.$gfirst[$j].'<td>';
                                                       ^---missing /
```

You're getting "extra" tags because that's what you're telling PHP to echo out...

Comment: Sometimes I feel like Homer Simpson...[D'oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'oh!)!

Comment: just don't go around strangling people... some folks frown on that sort of thing.

Comment: Good point! I try to avoid such things. :)